# como capturar values enviados siempre si o si sale el primero de arriba y no los de abajo

Tags: php, html, ajax

¿Por que cuando hago click en la casilla value 5 o 3 me sale siempre el value 2 en el capture del print?

veran tengo el siguiente html

```
<div><button onclick="bdma();" id="busquedadma" value="2" type="button" style="width: 95%; background:#E4EEaE;" name="2">El usuario es (cxzcsa) de nombre completo (Pepito xczas)</button></div>
<div><button onclick="bdma();" id="busquedadma" value="3" type="button" style="width: 95%; background:#E4EEaE;" name="3">El usuario es (xczv) de nombre completo (Pedro czxase)</button></div>
<div><button onclick="bdma();" id="busquedadma" value="5" type="button" style="width: 95%; background:#E4EEaE;" name="5">El usuario es (xczv) de nombre completo (Pecas czxase)</button></div>
<script>
function bdma(){
    var dct = document.getElementById('busquedadma').value;
    var parametros = {
        'docente'   : dct
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: './includes/busquedadma.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            $('#dmar').html(response);
        }
    });
}
</script><div id="dmar"></div>
```

Realizo el capture en un archivo php con el siguiente script

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
die('');
?>
```

dicho de otra manera por que la primera pregunta no se entendio.

¿la pregunta es como hago para que cada button, si hago click ya no me siga saliendo el value 2 en el print y me muestre el value 3 o 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas repitiendo el **id** en todos ellos, y cuando haces esto:

```
var dct = document.getElementById('busquedadma').value;
```

solo te coge el primero que encuentra.

Por norma, en HTML **nunca** debes repetir **id** en la misma página para evitar cosas como esta.

### Solución

Dado que quieres ejecutar la función cada vez que marcas una casilla, puedes cambiar esto:

```
onclick="bdma();"
```

por esto:

```
onclick="bdma(this);"
```

donde le estarás pasando el elemento marcado directamente, sin necesidad de que uses el `getElementById()` para saber cual de ellos es.

Y en la función debes cambiar estas dos líneas:

```
function bdma(){
    var dct = document.getElementById('busquedadma').value;
```

por estas otras:

```
function bdma(elemento){
    var dct = elemento.value;
```

para recoger el dato de `this` en el parámetro `elemento`, y así poder consultar su `value` sin errores.

Y finalmente borra todos los `id="busquedadma"` pues ya no los necesitas más, y menos repetidos.